# Deleting Data in Cassandra Targetted by a Json File

Tags: json, bash, cassandra

I have a JSON file with 2 attributes per row, messageID and appKey,
and have a table in Cassandra named msg_log.
This table's rows have columns which correspond 2 attributes above.
I want to parse the JSON file and according to its values, delete the matching rows from msg_log.
I am using bash script to do this, other methods not allowed for the time being.
Is it possible to achive this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it could be possible if these attributes are matching partition key/clustering column. In this case use following approach:

- generate individual `DELETE FROM table WHERE attr1 = ... AND attr2 = ...` statements in your bash script, and out put them into file
- execute all statements via `cqlsh -f file_name`

Depending on the format of your JSON file, you may use `sed` (if your file has one JSON record per line), but the best way is to extract data using the [jq utility](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) that may work with JSON formatted different ways.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have a problem about jq. I described an array in bash script and passed the parsed jq array. The array i parsed has [ ] arround it, but  the  array i have created is using ( ), so it causes error when i pass the values from jq array.

Comment: Please add the sample of data & schema for a table.